Определить по дате какой это по счету день недели с начала месяца
Есть дата, например сегодня 11 августа 2024 и она выпала на воскресенье. Как определить алгоритмически, какое это по счету воскресенье в августе 2024-го? (В данном случае 2-е)



1 Пн
2 Вт
3 Ср
4 Чт
5 Пт
6 Сб
7 Вс
№







1
2
3
4
1


5
6
7
8
9
1
11
2


12
13
14
15
16
17
18
3


19
20
21
22
23
24
25
4


26
27
28
29
30
31

5



let date = new luxon.DateTime(2024, 8, 14);

function getWeekDayOfMonth(date) {
 let day = date.day; //14
 let weekday = date.weekday; //7 - в лаксоне дни недели идут по человечески пн-вс от 1 до 7
 return //? должно вернуть 2
}

100% есть какая-то элементарная формула с делением на цело или с остатоком от деления на 7, но не могу сообразить.

Используйте Math.ceil(date.getDate() / 7) - день недели здесь не важен, а важен день месяца: определяем, сколько "семидневок" (в т.ч. неполных) прошло с начала месяца до нужного числа.


function getWeekDayOfMonth(date) {
    return Math.ceil(date.getDate() / 7)
}

['2024-08-04', '2024-08-11', '2024-08-18', '2024-08-25', '2024-08-27']
    .forEach(d => console.log(`${d}: ${getWeekDayOfMonth(new Date(d))} ${new Date(d).toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', {weekday: 'long'})} с начала месяца`))




Сейчас сижу с рукой на лице от того, насколько было просто, спасибо большое!

Вы учитываете правило, что "первой неделей года считается та, на которую выпадает первый четверг года."?
